# Session issue with Django site on running on AWS Beanstalk

Tags: django, session, amazon-web-services

I'm running a Django site on AWS Beanstalk, and I'm running into a session issue when AWS spins up a new instance to handle traffic spikes.  Periodically, users who are editing content in /admin  are logged out when they attempt to save and their edits are lost.

Question is: **What's the best way to handle sessions in a multi-instance Django environment?**

Middleware settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
)
```

Cache settings (using AWS Elasticache):

**EDITED, originally stated location to be 127.0.0.1, which was incorrect**

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
    'LOCATION': 'cache.mydomain.com:11211',
  }
}
```

Session settings:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'
```

I also tried:

```
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
```

But that didn't work.

Should I consider database-backed sessions?  I'm concerned about the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use cached sessions you'll need to keep the cache in one place rather than on 127.0.0.1--that way all AWS instances would have access to the same cache and the session data would be accessible to all of them, rather than each AWS instance only having access to its own cache.

If you don't want to or can't do that, you could consider a db-backed session option. For example, `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db` should work because of its being db-backed, even if the cache data occasionally becomes unavailable. The performance for this one does a hit on writes, because writes are sent to the db, but not to reads, where it only checks the DB if the cache data is unavailable or missing.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  It turns out that the cache settings I listed above were erroneous.  There's another settings file included that overrides the Cache settings to point to a shared cache on AWS Elasticache.  I've updated the original question accordingly.  So, still a mystery.

Comment: I'd try the db-backed session engine, then, as mentioned. I don't know enough about your cache setup, but if cache data is dropping out unexpectedly and you need the session data to remain, that's a solid way to do it.

Comment: We switched to db backed sessions and the issue appears to be fixed.  Still not sure why cached sessions weren't working (even with the shared cache).  Thanks for your help.